# Nusach of Tefilas Geshem

Tags: tefilla, song-poetry, moshe-rabbeinu, chukas, geshem-tal-ruach

In [Tefilas Geshem](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47847&st=%D7%A2%D7%9C+%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%9C%D7%A2&pgnum=560) we say "Al HaSela Hach Vayeitzu Mayim"

translated by Artscroll as:

> Remember the one [Moses] drawn forth in a bulrush basket from the
>   water. They said, 'He drew water and provided the sheep with water.'
>   At the time Your treasured people thirsted for water, **he struck the
>   rock and out came water**.

So far I know, Moshe Rabeinu [was taken to task](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14084&st=&pgnum=264) over hitting the rock. Then why do we pray that in this Zechus we should get water???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from Artscroll's *Daily Dose* ed. 1 vol. 14 p. 272:

**Answer #1:** The author of these piyutim believes that Moshe's sin was not hitting the rock, but for some other reason.

Problem: Although it is not a sin, why mention it at all? The prayer is about recalling the *merits* of people relating to rain.

**Answer #2**: It is referring to the incident in Beshalach (as in msh210's answer).

Problem (Baruch She'amar): Ein kateigor naaseh saneigor (a prosecutor can't become a defendant); the rock recalls both instances.

Problem (R' Schwab): The piyut uses the word "sela," which is the word used in Chukas; if it were referring to Beshalach, it should have said "tzur" (the word used there).

**Answer #3** (Baruch She'amar): The premature death of tzadikim that comes as a result of punishment, atones (Yerushalmi, Yoma 1:1). Therefore, we *do* recall Mei Merivah, because it *is* a merit (since it atones)!

**Answer #4** (R' Schwab): Although Moshe sinned, the water coming out was nevertheless a miracle and kidush Hashem, so it is also partially a merit.

Answer (score 1):

It happened twice, you know. [The first time](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/T0217) he was supposed to hit it, did so, and wasn't taken to task. I have no source, but imagine the *piyut* is referring to this.

Comment: It is interesting though that the time _Moshe_ was not taken to task, the rock is called a _tzur_; the time he was, it's called a _sela_; and the _piyut_ uses the word _sela_. So this answer is actually somewhat weak.

Comment: More at http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5199524#5199524 et seq.

Comment: ...and see [the other (much better) answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17445).

Answer (score 1):

The following is taken from the Torah Tavlin parsha sheet - Chukas 5774

> The word להקדישני explains Rashi, is meant to denote Kiddush Hashem. Had Moshe spoken to the rock, as Hashem
>   commanded, and not hit it the way he did, it would have created a great sanctification of Hashem’s name, and the people would
>   say, “Look how the rock, which does not speak or hear and needs no sustenance, fulfills the word of Hashem, so should we!”
>
> R’ Simcha Sheps ZT”L points out that when we say the special prayer for rain, Tefillas HaGeshem, we mention the merit
>   of Moshe hitting the rock: על הסלע הך ויצא מים, בצדקו חון חשרת מים - “He hit the rock and water came out; in the merit of his
>   righteousness grant us an abundance of water.” If Moshe was punished for hitting the rock, why do we mention this as a merit?
>   Commentaries on the prayer point out that these words are in reference to the end of Parshas Beshalach when the nation cried
>   out for water and Hashem told Moshe that he was to hit the rock by Chorev and water will come out from it. (Shemos 17:7)
>
> But why did Moshe hit the rock instead of speaking to it in this parsha? R’ Sheps learns from here the incredible depth of
>   mesirus nefesh (giving one’s all) that Moshe had for his people. If he would speak to the rock and it would give water, it would be a terrible accusation
>   on Klal Yisroel. When you talk to a rock it listens to Hashem, but when you talk to Klal Yisroel they don’t listen? So he hit the
>   rock and jeopardized himself for the benefit of the people. Thus, בצדקו חון - in the merit of this righteous deed have favor,
>   חשרת מים - and give us an abundance of water! However, although Moshe’s intention was entirely pure and self effacing, he
>   was punished , because there is no place for one’s own calculations and reasoning in the face of Hashem’s command!